# how to access public functions within .as file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to use ExternalInterface as I normally would and access public functions of an .as file (connect.as) from main.swf. I can make the swf with zero errors but I'm not seeing logs and functions...

for example there is a function called create

```
public function create(webSocketId:int,url:String,protocols:Array,proxyHost:String=null,proxyPort:int= 0,headers:String=null):void {
```

I try to call it even from within connect.as

```
create(0,'ws://mysie.com:8004',undefined,undefined,undefined);
```

Ps: i have checked that the above code is normally what is passed in.

main.swf << I've given the document the class of connect.as

connect.as:

```
package net.gimite.websocket {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    import flash.system.Security;
    import flash.utils.setTimeout;
    import mx.utils.URLUtil;

    ExternalInterface.call('consol.log',"flash hello");//<----not working

        public class WebSocketMain extends Sprite implements IWebSocketLogger{

        //there are lots of public functions I'm trying to access from main.swf in here
```

main.swf doesn't like line two in this attempt:

```
import connect;
var connect:Connect = new Connect();
connect.create(10,'ws://mysite.com:8004',undefined,undefined,undefined);
```

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 2   1026: Constructor functions must be instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

Place `ExternalInterface.call('consol.log',"flash hello");` inside constructor of `class WebSocketMain` or inside any other functions as Placing it outside the class doesn't make sense.

Comment: oh right!? I thought when I started this was similar to javascript... very painful, almost apple

Comment: that doesn't work. And how do you then start a function if you must already be inside a function?